# Creating SAML 2.0 Response with C# and .NET 4.5 in IDP Initiated web SSO

Tags: c#-4.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs3.0, component-space

I am doing web sso integration  (IDP initiated flow) for our web app(a CRM portal) in which users log in with AD credentials and accesses  resources on a Service Provider(SP) by passing in our customer details.Our server is on windows 2012 R2(ADFS 3.0).Can I have the SP post the SAML request to  a web api (4.6,C#) ,create the SAML 2.0 Response using third party assemblies([ComponentSpace](https://www.componentspace.com/)) and send it to the SP after digitally signing and Encrypting the assertion rather than relying on ADFS 3.0 to generate the SAML 2.0 Response?.Our SP wants some custom attributes added to the SAML response and the claim info resides on a sql server database. Do you  see any security problem generating the SAML response manually(Inside the Web API) rather than relying on ADFS 3.0?The reasoning behind manually creating SAML response is working with ADFS 3.0 is complex and our support team is too busy to look at our support tickets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting in touch with ComponentSpace support,it turns out that I don't have to use ADFS to create SAML response.All I have to do is get the claim details from sql server database and pass that onto  their SAMLIdentityProvider.InitiateSSO() as described [on their forum](https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/8149/Role-ComponentSpace-API-plays?Update=1#bm8170)

Update:
Use of componentspace library was not an option because of the organization delays associated with getting the approval and I ended up creating the saml response manually [thanks to this GitHub Repo](https://github.com/covermymeds/saml-http-post-reference)